# Download product image

Tags: magento-1.9

**How to get all image of a single product in magento and also click on download 
button to its download**

http://foo.com

Answer (score 1):

Get all images of single product:

```
<?php foreach ($product->getMediaGalleryImages() as $image) :?>

<img src="<?php echo Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'image', $image->getFile())->resize(100, 100); ?>" alt="<?php echo $product->getName()?>" />

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

For Image download, you can add "download" attribute in anchor tag. for example:

```
<a href="/images/myw3schoolsimage.jpg" download>
  <img border="0" src="/images/myw3schoolsimage.jpg" alt="W3Schools" width="104" height="142">
</a>
```

The image will download on click.